# JSF 2.0 sample or open source application

Tags: jsf-2

Does anyone know a complete JSF 2.0 sample or open source application using JSF 2.0 features (Facelets, Composite Component, Templates, Ajax, Navigation, etc.). Would be a good reference to learn some best practices. I'm talking about an application that you would also use in production. The only ones I know are ScrumToys and PetCatalog which are delivered with NetBeans 6.9 and are "tutorial-like" applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are few open source projects beeing hosted in [Kenai](http://www.kenai.com). You can find [here some JSF applications](http://kenai.com/projects_tags/jsf).